# WCF- Method unable to generate response. Is there any length limit for response header?

Tags: wcf, basichttpbinding

I have a WCF method returning custom list of objects and its about 20K records. Everything is working fine on my local machine but on live server method is unable to produce any response.
I am using below binding configs:

```
<bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="NewBinding0" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00"
          sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

Could anyone help me to fix this?

Kind Regards,
Micky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally , I have managed to fix it & fix is to add below setting in WCF server config.

```
 <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
<dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" /> 
</behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following section to your application config file and then make sure the folder it is writing trace to exists (c:\temp\WCFLogs in the example below).
You should start to see a ServerWCFTraces.svclog file be created - it might say 0 bytes in length until you stop your service or it decides to flush to disk.

Once you have reproduced your failure case, open up the log file on a machine with Visual Studio on (or download the viewer from here : [SvcTraceViewer from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

There's some instructions to use the tool on that MSDN link, but effectively you look for the errors (highlighted in red) in the activity pane (left), then zero in on the action which failed (top right pane) and in the details section (bottom right pane), there will be a description of the inner exception which is being thrown, which almost always tells you which explicit limit was breached and what attribute/property to increase to resolve it.

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <sources>
     <source propagateActivity="true" name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing">
        <listeners>
           <add name="ServiceModelMessageLoggingListener">
              <filter type="" />
           </add>
        </listeners>
     </source>
     <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" switchValue="Warning,ActivityTracing">
        <listeners>
           <add name="ServiceModelMessageLoggingListener">
              <filter type="" />
           </add>
        </listeners>
     </source>
  </sources>
  <sharedListeners>
     <add initializeData="C:\temp\WCFLogs\ServerWCFTraces.svclog" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" name="ServiceModelMessageLoggingListener" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp">
        <filter type="" />
     </add>
  </sharedListeners>
</system.diagnostics>
```

Comment: Hi dear, Thank you. I have tried this and ite giving me below error - "WCF service binding content type mismatch - text/xml and application/soap+xml"                                                                                                                                       I have below link configuration in my server & client configs:                                                                                         http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29050538/wcf-production-server-only-an-error-occurred-while-receiving-the-http-respon